# Regex between and including characters across multiple lines

Tags: c#, regex, csv

I have the below text:

```
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Zoning Letter
>>DocDate: 4/16/2014
Loan Number: 355211
Ad Hoc: ZONING VERIFICATION LETTER
Document Handle: 712826
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 367
>>NumOfPages: 0
>>FileSize: 261711
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 1
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 16
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V367\2855\1558564.PDF
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Zoning Letter
>>DocDate: 4/16/2014
Loan Number: 355211
Ad Hoc: ZONING CODES COMPLIANCE LETTER
Document Handle: 712825
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 367
>>NumOfPages: 0
>>FileSize: 19441
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 1
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 16
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V367\2855\1558563.pdf
```

I need to use regex (which will go in a C# program) to convert this into something effective for a CSV.  The data that is most vital is the document handle and filename (path) from each section (being a section under "BEGIN:")  I'm working on this for someone else, so I'd like to retain as much as possible in the event they decide they need some of the other data. This was my initial attempt:

```
\r\n(?!BEGIN).*\:
```

However, not every section has an "Ad Hoc:" component, which throws off the cell alignment when pulled into Excel.  Ad Hoc I know for sure is not part of the data that is needed for the end result.

The best case scenario would be to just select and remove everything between every "Ad Hoc" and "Handle:" to be replaced with the delimiter (;).  I would then pipe this along with my above regex.

My only other requirement is that this has to all be in one regex statement - otherwise in the program I've written I'll have to set up some sort of loop or while business which I'm not prepared to do yet.

Comment: *"My only other requirement is that this has to all be in one regex statement - otherwise [...] I'll have to set up some sort of loop [...] which I'm not prepared to do yet".* I am not saying that it is impossible, but much, much luck and fun with that monster of a regex just to avoid trivial loops...

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think it doesn't have to be a monster.  I think I really just need something that selects everything  from the beginning of "Ad Hoc" through "Handle:" which would do the same thing as what I have above just across a line break.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Ahh, so you want to actually filter out/remove/exclude the (optional) "Ad Hoc" part before further processing (or Excel import) of the data (and not necessarily using a Regex for the processing itself)?

Comment: Correct - the regex is just what my program will use to prepare the text files (exported from a documents database) for integration into another spreadsheet.

Comment: I've cobbled this together: (\r\n(?!BEGIN).*\:)|(Ad Hoc([\s\S]*?)Document Handle\:) but it somehow still leaves in what is between Ad Hoc and Document Handle.  Can I maybe modify the above to remove that portion i.e. ZONING VERIFICATION LETTER?

Comment: Just to be clear: All you want to do is to remove **complete** "Ad Hoc" lines, or do you want to achieve empty "Ad Hoc:" lines, or is there something more/else? (Because, why would you even bother with "BEGIN" if all you are concerned about is removing "Ad Hoc" lines...)

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the ad hoc lines (if they exist) in their entirety.  The reason I exclude "BEGIN" is because when I'm removing line breaks I want each row to start with BEGIN instead of one giant string. - I just pasted in the first two documents/information, the text files I'm working with have anywhere between 20-200 sections that begin with BEGIN.

Comment: To summarize: You want one RegEx which removes "Ad Hoc:" lines, and which also replaces line breaks except in front of "BEGIN" with ";". Correct?

Comment: Yes - but not just the line breaks; everything between a line break and a colon...this gets rid of the category headings (i.e. Loan number, etc.)

Comment: Okay, i answered your question as far as i understood it. I also put examples of expected output, so it should be easier to verify whether my answer is what you want, or whether i misunderstood you somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what i understood from the comments underneath the question, the example data given in the question should be transformed into two text lines like this:

```
Zoning Letter;4/16/2014;355211;712826;102;367;0;261711;0;1;0;0;16;0;2;0;0;\V367\2855\1558564.PDF
Zoning Letter;4/16/2014;355211;712825;102;367;0;19441;0;1;0;0;16;0;2;0;0;\V367\2855\1558563.pdf
```

To achieve this result while avoiding a loop (although i wonder why you would want to avoid loops - they are basic and omni-present constructs), i would suggest applying two (or three, see section 3. below) regex substitutions.

**1. Removal of "Label:" and replacement of line breaks with ";"**

The first regular expression will remove a label in front of ":" including ":" and any preceding line break with a semicolon. However, it will *not* remove or replace a line break in front of "BEGIN:", and neither will it touch the "BEGIN:" itself.

```
@"(([\r\n]+\s*Ad\sHoc:.*?[\r\n]+)|([\r\n]+(?!\s*BEGIN))).*?:\s*"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex is an OR-combination of two regex (which is easy to see in the visualization above):

```
[\r\n]+\s*Ad\sHoc:.*?[\r\n]+.*?:\s*
```

which will match Ad Hoc:" lines including any "Label:" string in the following line, and

```
([\r\n]+(?!\s*BEGIN)).*?:\s*
```

which will match any "Label:" including the line break in front of it, except for the "BEGIN:" label.

Applying this regex to your example and replacing all matches with ";" will result in the following:

```
BEGIN:;Zoning Letter;4/16/2014;355211;712826;102;367;0;261711;0;1;0;0;16;0;2;0;0;\V367\2855\1558564.PDF
BEGIN:;Zoning Letter;4/16/2014;355211;712825;102;367;0;19441;0;1;0;0;16;0;2;0;0;\V367\2855\1558563.pdf
```

Note the "BEGIN:;" which we will take care of now.

**2. Elimination of the "BEGIN:" labels**

This is rather simple pattern when looking at the result of the first regex substitution.

```
"(?m)^BEGIN:;"
```

You might think that you can do this through a string replacement - and so did i when writing the first version of my answer. However, a mere string replacement would become a problem when "BEGIN:;" could be part of the content of any other text field. Better to be correct and safe by specifying a regex which matches only at the beginning of a line.

**3. Code example, including elimination of empty lines in the source text**

If you have empty lines containing white-spaces in the source text, the regular expression displayed above might not work properly. The solution is to do another regex substitution beforehand, which reduces empty lines (including white-spaces) to a single line break (if you are certain that your source data does not contain empty lines, you can omit this step).

A complete code example, which would produce the result as mentioned at the beginning of my answer, could look like this:

```
string sourceData = ... your text with the source data ...

Regex reEmptyLines = new Regex(@"[\s\r\n]+[\r\n]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
Regex reSemicolons = new Regex(@"(([\r\n]+\s*Ad\sHoc:.*?[\r\n]+)|([\r\n]+(?!\s*BEGIN))).*?:\s*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
Regex reBegin = new Regex("(?m)^BEGIN:;", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string processed =
    reBegin.Replace(
        reSemicolons.Replace(
            reEmptyLines.Replace(sourceData, "\r\n"),
            ";"
        ),
        string.Empty
    );
```

Comment: This works perfectly - took me a minute to figure out how to add the code into what I have so far, but I found your explanation very helpful.  I was avoiding loops because I have never done one, and wanted to ask one question at a time.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @hispeedzintarwebz, if you can read and understand regular expressions, then loops should be a no-brainer for you :-D

Comment: I tried adding in more lines to remove via the pipe character around the "ad hoc" statement...and when I add one more, it works.  When I add two or more, they aren't selected.  What is the best way to manipulate this by adding to the above example?  As I pulled more input text files I have realized there are more things that change between them...I'm really only needing the file path and document handle, so I started trying to get rid of other lines.

Comment: @hispeedzintarwebz, it is probably better to ask this as a new SO question, including the (changed) input data you have to deal with now, what the expected result should be and what (modified?) regex you use. From your comment i do not really get a grasp on what your new input data and your modified regex look like exactly, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex, but I wouldn't say it is easier than doing it in cycle manually.

```
(?<=BEGIN:\r\n)(?:.*:\s*(?:(?<value>(?<!Ad Hoc:\s*).*)|.*)(?:\r\n)?)*?(?=BEGIN:|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Sample code:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=BEGIN:\r\n)(?:.*:\s*(?:(?<value>(?<!Ad Hoc:\s*).*)|.*)(?:\r\n)?)*?(?=BEGIN:|$)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", m.Groups["value"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value)));
}
```

Output:

```
Zoning Letter,4/16/2014,355211,712826,102,367,0,261711,0,1,0,0,16,0,2,0,0,\V367\2855\1558564.PDF
Zoning Letter,4/16/2014,355211,712825,102,367,0,19441,0,1,0,0,16,0,2,0,0,\V367\2855\1558563.pdf
```

Comment: @hispeedzintarwebz, "<value>" denotes the name of a group in the regex. Look at in the regex at the group `(?<value>(?<!Ad Hoc:\s*).*)`. The pattern of that group is "(?<!Ad Hoc:\s*).*", which Ulugbek gave the name "value". This, way it is very easy to access the matched text of that group in code like `m.Groups["value"]`.

Comment: Gotta love the visualization. Need to put this in my answer, too :)

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
BEGIN:((?:(?!BEGIN:).)*)
```

This would match everything between the first BEGIN and the next.

Comment: why so complicated? `BEGIN:.*?(?=BEGIN:|$)` would do the same, but still it doesn't solve OP problem.

Comment: I tried this and it just removed every instance of "BEGIN" and replaced it with the semicolon.

Comment: @hispeedzintarwebz: Oh you have to set the (. matches newline flag) but nevermind I seem to have not understood your question.