# Removing entire lines from text with regex, ignoring duplicates and only leaving lines according to criteria

Tags: c#, regex, csv

I've been working on a project to manipulate text files in c# into something usable that I can pull into excel as a CSV.  I asked another question a few weeks ago which was a definite step in the right direction, however I have some additional constraints that I am trying to figure out.

Link to previous question for background: [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684844/regex-between-and-including-characters-across-multiple-lines/23686350?noredirect=1#comment36992448_23686350)

The input text file (an example of which is below) has several types of data associated with documents that are stored in a database.  The data is broken into sections for each document, which is denoted by a "BEGIN:".  The original regular expression removed most of the line breaks, removed data labels, as well as a line labeled "Ad Hoc" which I elected to remove because it was not present in every file, so when I brought it into excel it would misalign the columns.

After looking at additional text files that were the output of this database, I have discovered that there are more inconsistencies, so since I really only need 2 or 3 pieces of data from this, I think it would be easiest to remove everything except what is needed.

I tried to use pipes (which I have come to understand is an "or" operator in regex) to try to add additional conditions to the expression, but once I added more than one additional condition it would start to skip the following conditions.

Here are my requirements, and below I will paste in example text:

1. I only need 2 data items from each document section: Document Handle and FileName.
2. At the bottom of the text file there is an additional portion of the file path denoted by "\"
3. In some text files, filename and the path at the bottom are repeated, but are the same

The text files which are the output of the document database we are using is pretty useless as it is.  My goal is to be able to pull something into excel which has the document handle and filename for each document (each section starting with "BEGIN:" is a separate document) and the complete file path at the bottom.  So far I have been using a semicolon to deliniate the text when pulling it into excel.

Sample Text:

```
>>>>Self Configuring Tagged DIP<<<<
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: System Maintenance Forms
>>DocDate: 3/18/2013
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: sample
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Document Handle: 599954
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 110
>>NumOfPages: 0
>>FileSize: 303909
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 1
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 16
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V110\1366\798567.pdf
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Post Closing Contact Sheet
>>DocDate: 3/18/2013
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: sample 
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Ad Hoc: 2013 02 26 BWR CONTACT INFO UPDATE FOORM
Document Handle: 599983
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 110
>>NumOfPages: 0
>>FileSize: 276653
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 1
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 16
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V110\1366\798596.pdf
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Insurance ACORD
>>DocDate: 1/11/2008
Policy Number: 91QB94439
Effective Date: 01/24/2008
Expiration Date: 01/24/2009
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: 3642 sample
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Document Handle: 98326
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 24
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 74839
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V24\202\133225.TIF
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 24
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 74839
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 1
>>ItemPageNum: 1
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V24\202\133225.TIF
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Insurance ACORD
>>DocDate: 1/2/2008
Policy Number: 91QB94439
Effective Date: 01/24/2008
Expiration Date: 01/24/2009
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: sample
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Document Handle: 94202
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 23
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 78846
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V23\194\128851.TIF
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 23
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 78846
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 1
>>ItemPageNum: 1
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V23\194\128851.TIF
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Insurance ACORD
>>DocDate: 12/6/2007
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: sample
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Document Handle: 89402
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 23
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 126946
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V23\184\123535.TIF
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 23
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 126946
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 1
>>ItemPageNum: 1
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V23\184\123535.TIF
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 23
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 126946
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 2
>>ItemPageNum: 2
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V23\184\123535.TIF
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 23
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 126946
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 3
>>ItemPageNum: 3
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V23\184\123535.TIF
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Insurance ACORD
>>DocDate: 4/11/2007
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: sample
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Document Handle: 24385
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 5
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 64763
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V5\47\35166.TIF
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Insurance ACORD
>>DocDate: 2/7/2007
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: sample
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Document Handle: 6272
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 1
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 135355
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V1\10\7921.TIF
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 1
>>NumOfPages: 1
>>FileSize: 135355
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 0
>>PhysicalPageNum: 1
>>ItemPageNum: 1
>>FileTypeNum: 2
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V1\10\7921.TIF
BEGIN:
>>DocTypeName: Assignment of Leases and Rents
>>DocDate: 10/18/2012
Loan Number: 893102103
Property Name: sample
Borrower Name: sample
Address: sample
City: DECATUR
State: GA
Ad Hoc: LOAN ASSUMPTION
Document Handle: 562703
>>DiskgroupNum: 102
>>VolumeNum: 102
>>NumOfPages: 0
>>FileSize: 623209
>>DocRevNum: 0
>>Rendition: 1
>>PhysicalPageNum: 0
>>ItemPageNum: 0
>>FileTypeNum: 16
>>ImageType: 0
>>Compress: 2
>>Xdpi: 0
>>Ydpi: 0
>>FileName: \V102\1300\760684.pdf
END:
InstallID: Laureate
Volume: 102,1,3997815,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\loan_admin,
Volume: 102,5,3999736,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\loan_admin,
Volume: 102,6,3998253,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\loan_admin,
Volume: 102,23,3999424,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,24,3998776,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,25,3985430,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,37,3999939,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,39,3999150,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,40,3999837,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,41,3999844,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,52,3999578,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,71,3998227,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,88,3992838,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,102,3999346,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,106,3999163,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,109,3999950,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,110,3996896,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,111,3999421,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,355,3998185,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Volume: 102,358,3971185,Loan Administration,\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\LOAN_ADMIN,
Doc Count: 30
```

The desired end result would be:

```
599954;\V110\1366\798567.pdf
599983;\V110\1366\798596.pdf
98326;\V24\202\133225.TIF
94202;\V23\194\128851.TIF
89402;\V23\184\123535.TIF
24385;\V5\47\35166.TIF
6272;\V1\10\7921.TIF
562703;\V102\1300\760684.pdf
\\gbcdconbase01\D\DiskGroups\loan_admin
```

Here is the original regex pattern from my previous question, which with two other patterns in sequence removed line breaks, data headings and "ad-hoc" lines, which may help.  This is where I tried adding headings from other lines with pipes near the "ad hoc" part of the pattern below.

```
(([\r\n]+\s*Ad\sHoc:.*?[\r\n]+)|([\r\n]+(?!\s*BEGIN))).*?:\s*
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this pattern is the closest to what you're looking for (there is an extra semi-colon at the bottom line)

```
.*?Document\sHandle:\s*(\d+).*?>>FileName:\s*(\V+)|.*Loan\sAdministration,([^,]+).*
```

and replace w/ `$1;$2$3\n` using `gs` modifiers
or perhaps replace w/ `$3$1;$2\n` then remove last character. 
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC7hT4)

Comment: I can't recommend using regular expressions here. Just loop through the lines, split, and output!

Comment: @alpha bravo - I'm sure this is not the most efficient way to accomplish this, but this should work - many thanks for your time.

Comment: It's throwing me an unrecognized escape sequence error on \V - which according to the regex 101 is "any non-vertical whitespace character..."  Is there a c# equivalent for this?

Comment: try replacing `\V` with `[^\r\n]`

Answer (score 2):

With these requirements, using regular expressions is not a recommended approach. Perhaps it is possible to craft a combination of Regex'es to fulfill this task, but it would be a royal pain to create and maintain such. For what you want to do, it is much easier to stick with simple string manipulation (which will also result in better readable and maintainable code).

Generally speaking, your code should do something like this:

1. Read the source file line-by-line and split each line into the *identifier* (the text before the first colon) and a *value* (the text after the first ":"). Store the information you are interested in some variables, or in a dictionary if you need to handle more than just a few data fields. (Since you only want to handle the "*Document Handle*" and "*FileName*" fields for now, it would be fine to use two string variables for that purpose.)
   Whenever the code encounters a "*BEGIN*" identifier, it writes the content of those variables (or of the dictionary) into the destination file in form of a semicolon-separated text line. After doing this, clear the values of the variables (or the dictionary). If those variables are empty (such as when encountering the very first "*BEGIN*"), there is of course no need to write something to the destination file.
2. If the code encounters the "*END*" identifier, let the remaining source file lines being read by another loop which processes the lines in a somewhat different manner. Now, only lines with a "*Volume*" identifier will be processed, any other line will be ignored.
   To avoid output of duplicate volume paths, a `HashSet<string>` will be used to track the volume paths that have already been output. The *HashSet*  needs to be initialized with a [*StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase.aspx) comparer, since you seem to treat paths in a case-insensitive manner.
   Extract the path from the value string of the line with the "*Volume*" identifier (a simple [*string.Split*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) seems to do the job just fine, but to be sure you might want to look into how your particular input file format encodes text values containing commas), and check whether the path is already stored in the *HashSet*. If so, just ignore the path and continue with the next line of the source file.

   If the path is not yet in the *HashSet*, output it and also add it to the *HashSet*, then continue with the next line of the source file.

This more or less all your code has to do. Do not try to stick to regular expressions just because. The experience of you struggling to adapt the existing regular expression(s) to a slightly changed scenario is a very good example of why trying to do just everything with just a few gargantuan regex'es is not really making anyone's life easier (unless you enjoy the challenge ;) ). Also, you might think a little bit about how easy it will be for you (or another developer) to adapt a conventional code (such as roughly outlined above) in comparison to create yet another large regex whenever the application scenario or input files slightly change yet again...

Comment: I can definitely understand that regex is probably not the best way to go given the requirements...but I will admit that this is way over my head, I've sort of been cobbling this program together with no prior c# experience.  I'd hate to ask you to explain every piece of the explanation above, so I'm going to have to revisit this when I get a little more c# under my belt.  Much appreciated still.